# How to add multiple domain name in Google App Engine by our user for white-label?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have website in Google App Engine and I pointed a domain name (Example : mywebsite.com) in custom domain panel. This is a SAAS project so my users / customer add their domain name for white label.

This is for a Google App Engine serverless cloud by Google. and I want to add customer domain names.

When I add Cname at my domain provider dns system.
I add Cname like track.otherdomain.com to -> www.mywebsite.com

when when I open track.otherdomain.com it's display error 404.

So How can my users connect their domain name to my app engine hosted website for white labeling / own branding. (SAAS)

Comment: Why not configure `track.otherdomain.com` just like `www.mywebsite.com`? (i.e. CNAME pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com`)?

Comment: In addition, what's the content of you `dispatch.yaml` file?

Comment: dispatch:
  - url: "*/*"
    service: default